# Sylius web/assets folder is empty

Tags: sylius

Frontend and admin pages don't load the CSS and JS files. I am new to Sylius and Symfony. My assets folder is in /web/assets/ but it's blank. I tried running the below command.

```
php app/console assets:install
```

it outputs the following,

```
Some assets were installed via copy

  ✔   SyliusAttributeBundle          copy            
  ✔   SyliusShippingBundle           copy            
  ✔   SyliusReportBundle             copy            
  ✔   SyliusPromotionBundle          copy            
  ✔   SyliusAddressingBundle         copy            
  ✔   SyliusMetadataBundle           copy            
  ✔   SyliusReviewBundle             copy            
  ✔   SyliusResourceBundle           copy            
  ✔   FrameworkBundle                copy            
  ✔   JMSTranslationBundle           copy            
  ✔   WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle   copy
```

I ran the below command but nothing happend either.

```
$npm run gulp
```

Can someone explain to me if the assets are getting installed in a different location and not in web/assets/

Comment: First try running `npm install` then run `npm run gulp`

Comment: When I ran this, I used the command: app/console assets:install web. I'm not sure if that 'web' part is important. Furthermore, I usually have to dump assetic to update my web/assets folder with the new copies of the source assets I edit:  php app/console assetic:dump